# Installing ruby-debug-ide - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, ruby-debug-ide

I have win7x64 and struggling to install ruby-debug-ide to use debugger in my ide. It is failing to build gem native extensions
have tried everything i could find through net
--verbose, --pre, --with ruby etc

Its still failing (

Can anyone give some tip please? thanks

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]


$ gem install ruby-debug-ide
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
System cannot find path specified
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/ext
C:/Ruby231-x64/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
'Ёбв?┐? -? г¤ ?вбп - cвЁ гЄ § --лc Їгвм.
'Ёбв?┐? -? г¤ ?вбп - cвЁ гЄ § --лc Їгвм.
Installing base gem
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debase-0.2.2.beta9/ext
C:/Ruby231-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170120-10104-1f4a8us.rb extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... yes
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/debase-0.2.2.beta9/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debase-0.2.2.beta9 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/debase-0.2.2.beta9/gem_make.out
C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:92:in `run'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:48:in `block in build'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tempfile.rb:295:in `open'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:31:in `build'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:164:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:163:in `chdir'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:163:in `block in build_extension'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:162:in `synchronize'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:162:in `build_extension'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:201:in `block in build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `each'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:752:in `build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:304:in `install'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:97:in `install'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:166:in `block in install'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:156:in `each'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:156:in `install'
  C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:405:in `install'
  mkrf_conf.rb:35:in `rescue in <main>'
  mkrf_conf.rb:28:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby231-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/gem_make.out


$ gem install debase-ruby_core_source
Successfully installed debase-ruby_core_source-0.9.6


$ gem install debase -- --with-ruby-include=C:\Ruby231-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\debase-ruby_core_source-0.9.6\lib\debase\ruby_core_source\ruby-2.3.1-p112
Building native extensions with: '--with-ruby-include=C:\Ruby231-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\debase-ruby_core_source-0.9.6\lib\debase\ruby_core_source\ruby-2.3.1-p112ruby -v'
This could take a while...
System cannot find path specified
ERROR:  Error installing debase:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


$ gem install debase --pre
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
System cannot find path specified
ERROR:  Error installing debase:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

$ gem install ruby-debug-ide --pre
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta4/ext
C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
'Ёбв?┐? -? г¤ ?вбп - cвЁ гЄ § --лc Їгвм.
'Ёбв?┐? -? г¤ ?вбп - cвЁ гЄ § --лc Їгвм.
Installing base gem
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debase-0.2.2.beta9/ext
C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170201-7760-7dws4t.rb extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... yes
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/debase-0.2.2.beta9/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debase-0.2.2.beta9 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/debase-0.2.2.beta9/gem_make.out
C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:91:in `run'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:36:in `block in build'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tempfile.rb:295:in `open'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:19:in `build'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:163:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:162:in `chdir'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:162:in `block in build_extension'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `synchronize'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `build_extension'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:200:in `block in build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:197:in `each'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:197:in `build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:741:in `build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:290:in `install'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:166:in `block in install'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:150:in `each'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:150:in `install'
  C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:404:in `install'
  mkrf_conf.rb:35:in `rescue in <main>'
  mkrf_conf.rb:28:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby231-x64_unit/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta4/gem_make.out
```